# Android application doesnt connect to Google play services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-api-client

I tried to connect my app with Google play services, first off all to log in with Google+ account. The loading screen for the play services on connect appears, but somehow the googleApiClient doesn't connect, i always come to the method "onConnectionFailed".

Dependencies in Gradle:

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.8.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.8.+'
```

onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiplayer_turn_based);

        //signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonCheckGames = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheckGames);
        buttonStartMatch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartMatch);

        // Create the Google API Client with access to Plus and Games
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
                .build();


    }
```

for sign in:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    mSignInClicked = true;
                    mTurnBasedMatch = null;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    break;
                case R.id.sign_out_button:
                    mSignInClicked = false;
                    Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);


findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //  Log.d(TAG, "onStart(): Connecting to Google APIs");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


}
```

There login screen appears for "Play Games" as a popup, but it doesn't connect  due to "unknown problem with Google Play services" error.

I configured the App with the dev console using: https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling , sha1 key and app_id are involved, but I don't know what the problem is :/ Testing on external advice with Android API 21, latest "Play Games"-version and internet access. Maybe someone can help me, want to implement this is my bachelor thesis.

Comment: Do you have any error logs or anything from your logcat to share? That might contain something that'll help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the problem was i tried to connect over a second Activity, i tried it again in the main Activity and it works :)